# Rest query params in Java

Tags: parse-platform

I need to do some queries against my datastore in Java but I can't seem to get the parameters syntax right. I tried like this:

```
String params = "?Active=1";
String urlString = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Cars" + params;
```

Or as per the document [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries):

```
String params = "where={Active:1}";
```

But both ways generate an exception.

If I don't do the query and simply try to get all the objects with this request string:

```
String urlString = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Cars"
```

everything works fine. So the problem is definitely the params sequence. So is there a way to do `Prase.com` rest queries in Java?

EDIT: adding the exception string in response to a request from the first comment:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Cars?where={Active:1}
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

I should also note that when I use the regular `http` syntax, as in

```
params = "?Dealer=asdf";
```

the query comes back with all the objects, as if the parameter wasn't there.

Comment: Please paste the exception and maybe the code where the query is sent.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I added it to the question.

Comment: Have you tried running the queries manually? Maybe you missed part of their API

Comment: @Dave how do you mean manually?

Comment: By opening a browser or some http tool and opening that url, to look at the result. E.g. click here: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Cars?where={Active:1} and notice that it asks for authorisation. Maybe that's what you forgot to include?

Comment: No, that's not it. I tried putting in my my app id and rest key but it just asks for authentication again.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of working examples for the params string:

```
String params = "where={\"objectId\":\"ldl49l3kd98\"}";

String params = "where={\"CompanyName\":\"BMW\", \"Price\":{\"$gte\":29000,\"$lte\":49000}}";
```

And if you need non English characters, like I do, encode the param string like this:

```
params = URLEncoder.encode(params, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Where would we add the parameters into the request? Would we access those parameters in cloud code by request.params?

Comment: @JMStudios.jrichardson you add these parameters in your application code. Then you get them in the cloud by calling request.params.ParamName.

Comment: @Eddy can you please post an example of adding a username parameter to a httlpurlconnection object? I am having a lot of trouble with the parameters. Would you rather I make a new post?

Comment: @Eddy here is the question I posted.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252869/java-passing-parameters-to-parse-com-cloud-code-function

Comment: Hi, sorry, I haven't touched this in a while. Hopefully someone from Parse.com would take a look at it. Good luck!